# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Estoy teniendo este error que he visto que se soluciona mientras sea cerrando todos los paréntesis, pero he revisado y no tengo ninguno abierto.

```
numero = (int("Dame el numero de la tabla de multiplicar: "))
for x in (range(1,10)
    (print (str(x))+ " * "+ (str(numero))+ " * "+ (str(numero *x)))
```

Esto es exactamente lo que el error me dice:

```
 File "tabla_n.py", line 4

                                                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 4? Tienes muchos paréntesis, hay uno innecesario que comienza antes del `range()` y otro que antecede al `print()`. Los `str()` tampoco necesitan ir dentro de un paréntesis.

Comment: ```File "tabla_n.py", line 2
    for x in range(1,10)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```                                                                                                       Me está dando ese error de momento si quito los parentesis

Comment: Le faltó el `:` final

Comment: La flecha está señalando al parentesis al lado del 10

Comment: ```numero = (int("Dame el numero de la tabla de multiplicar: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Dame el numero de la tabla de multiplicar: ``` Ahora me da ese error, qué significa?

Comment: `int()` hace que el contenido lo convierta en un número entero pero el contenido es un string no numérico. Olvidaste un `input()` entre el `int()` y el string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por partes:

- Te falta llamar a `input` en la primera línea para obtener la entrada del usuario. El paréntesis alrededor de `int(....)` es innecesario.
- En la línea del `for` te falta cerrar el paréntesis que abres antes de `range`, es más no necesitas ese paréntesis. Te falta también los `:` al final de la expresión.
- La mitad de los paréntesis que hay en la línea del `print` te sobran:

  ```
  print(str(x) + " * " + str(numero) + " * " + str(numero * x))
  ```

No obstante, en vez de esa "horrible", **poco legible** e **ineficiente** línea concatenando cadenas, usa formateo de cadenas, dado que usas Python >= 3.6 usa literales de cadena formateados:

```
numero = int(input("Dame el numero de la tabla de multiplicar: "))
for x in range(1, 10):
    print(f"{x} X {numero} = {numero * x}")
```

Más simple, más legible, no tienes que hacer el casting explícito a `str` y encima son mucho más eficientes. El concatenado de cadenas debe evitarse en lo posible, al ser objeto inmutables concatenar implica crear un nuevo objeto por cada concatenación. Antes de los f'strings para concatenar más de dos cadenas era más eficiente usar formateo de cadenas, actualmente `f'string` es más eficiente incluso si solo son dos.

Answer (score 2):

Por el texto en tu código asumo que quieres pedir al usuario un número. Para ello, en la siguiente línea debes agregar la función `"input()"`. Esta función te retorna un `str`, por lo que debes convertirlo a `int` para realizar cálculos posteriores:

```
numero = int(input("Dame el numero de la tabla de multiplicar: "))
```

También, debes tener en cuenta qué paréntesis son realmente necesarios y cuales no, así como no dejar ninguno abierto. Tampoco olvides agregar `:` cuando utilizas un `for` loop. El código completo con los ajustes quedaría así:

```
numero = int(input("Dame el numero de la tabla de multiplicar: "))

for x in range(1,11):
    print(str(x) + " * " + str(numero) + " = " + str(numero * x))
```

Por último, te recomendaría agregar una función para validar que efectivamente el usuario ingresa un número y no una letra, o cualquier caracter especial.

Answer (score 1):

No sé exactamente lo que está intentando a hacer pero para solucionar el problema tiene que cerrar el paréntesis con el `range` y añadir `:`.

```
numero = (int("Dame el numero de la tabla de multiplicar: "))
for x in (range(1,10)):
    (print (str(x))+ " * "+ (str(numero))+ " * "+ (str(numero *x)))
```

Además está intentando a convertir un `str` a un `int` con el string en la primer linea lo cual no es posible y arrojará un error después de cerrar el paréntesis en `range`.

Finalmente, la conversion de `str(numero * x)` no es necesario como que la conversion es implícita en Python como puede ver abajo.

```
>>> s = "hola"
>>> s_multiplicado = s * 5
>>> type(s_multiplicado)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

Recomiendo los docs en types de Python para saber más de como funcionan.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que la conversión no es necesaria especialmente en este caso que la utiliza dentro de un print() que concatena `str` e `int`?

Comment: Bueno, de lo que sé, sí funciona con Python 3. ¡Pero, siempre estoy abierto para aprender si no es el caso!